# XSL add the sum of child nodes to a variable

Tags: xml, xslt, sum

```
<Recipes>
    <Food A="...">
        <Ingredients>
            <Ingredient Salt="...">
                <Qty> 250 </Qty>
                <Type> g </Type>
            </Ingredient>
             .
             .
        </Ingredients>
    </Food>

    <Food B="...">
        <Ingredients>
            <Ingredient Salt="...">
                <Qty> 30 </Qty>
                <Type> g </Type>
            </Ingredient>
             .
             .
        </Ingredients>
    </Food>

    <Food C="...">
        <Ingredients>
            <Ingredient Salt="...">
                <Qty> 25 </Qty>
                <Type> g </Type>
            </Ingredient>
             .
             .
        </Ingredients>
    </Food>
</Recipes>
```

Hello, i have a similar xml file like the one above and im trying to sum into a variable the amount of salt in differents foods, so for this example the result should be 305.

I tried multiple paths to the `sum()`, but i am not able to access the way i want. Is it possible to do this?

This is my last try, but it returns 0.

```
<xsl:variable name="Salt" select="sum(Recipes/*/Ingredients/Ingredient[name()='Salt']/@Qty)"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should works

```
<xsl:variable name="Salt" select="sum(/Recipes/*/Ingredients/Ingredient[@Salt]/Qty)" />
```